# Classic ASP on Localhost, no form data?

Tags: forms, asp-classic, localhost, iis-5

I have a really odd situation going on on my local PC that I can not seems to resolve.

Recently I have been contacted to extend a classic ASP website that I wrote a few years back. I unpacked the code into a sub folder of wwwroot on my current machine running XP pro. It has never had any classic ASP sites running on it. I set up IIS and create an application and run the website on my localhost. The site renders correctly and appears to run fine. Except one thing... The post data seems to get lost.

I have entered `Response.Write("[" & Request.Form & "]")` at the top of one of my pages and just renders "[]". Can any one advise as to why I may be losing the form data? The website used to work fine on my last machine running XP Pro, as that is the machine I developed it on. What have I forgotten to set up?

The html form code looks like

```
<form name="frmAdminLogin" actionAdminLogin.asp" method="post"  >
    <input type="hidden" name="hidFormAction" value="frmAdminLogin" >

  <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0"  >
    <tr>
      <td width="40%"  align="right"  valign="top" >Username: </td>
      <td width="60%"  align="left"  valign="top" >
        <input type="text" name="txtUsername" value="" size="25" maxlength="25" tabindex="1" class="TextBox" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="40%"  align="right"  valign="top" >Password: </td>
      <td width="60%"  align="left"  valign="top" >
        <input type="password" name="txtPassword" value="" size="25" maxlength="25" tabindex="2" class="TextBox" >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%"  colspan="2"  align="center"  valign="top" >
        <input type="submit" name="btnLogIn" value="Log In" tabindex="3" class="Button"  >
        <input type="reset" name="btnReset" value="Reset" tabindex="4" class="Button"  >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  </form>
```

Comment: It appears that it is not an IIS issue after all but an Internet Explorer issue. The post data is present when I use Opera Browser.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo here, but maybe fixing actionAdminLogin.asp" to action="AdminLogin.asp" in your form tag will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that it is not an IIS issue after all but an Internet Explorer issue. The post data is present when I use Opera Browser.

I think this is correct - there is some bug (feature?) of Internet Explorer which prevents form data being submitted if there is only a single form element.  If you add a extra element (hidden field, it really doesn't matter) it should work properly.

I'll try to expand this comment when I get a chance but my work firewall is preventing my finding the blog posts which originally pointed me in the right direction.